# Show categories associated with a list of channel entries

Tags: channel-entries, categories, filtering

I'm wanting to filter a list of product entries with Ajax and I am wanting to create a dropdown list of all categories associated with the current list of entries.

eg. I have 100 products that have a main category and have all been assigned a category or two for filtering. In the dropdown list, I want to show ONLY the filtering categories that have been assigned to the current list of products.

So far, I've got a list of ALL categories from a group and not the limited list based on the products in the main category.

I'm currently playing with the query module to see if I can filter the category list down to the correct list of filtering categories.

Its a tough one to explain, but I hope I have done a good job.

Does anyone know the best approach?

I've test GWcodes categories and provided a list of entry_ids, however this shows up a list duplicated categories. Basically the right result, but I get duplicates.

Any help and guidance would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: U looking to replicate something like isotope js functionality ?

Comment: Hi Stuartmcd69 - Kind of, but not really. I'm using JPList. Similar functionality, but slightly different. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have easy access to the entry_ids of the visible entries as a comma-separated list, this query should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cat_id FROM exp_category_posts WHERE entry_id IN(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could benefit from a module like this: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/reefine

Might save re-inventing wheel, maybe.